# DatePicker (material-ui-picker) onChange unable to pass the value to redux-form onChange event

Tags: material-ui, redux-form

Integrating DatePicker from material-ui-picker with redux-form.

DatePicker onChange is not able to pass the current value to the onChange of redux-form, code below for reference

helper.js=>>> DatePicker Wrapper

```
export const DatePickerField = ({
  label,
  input: { onChange, value, name }, 
  meta: { error, form }, 
  minDate,
  maxDate,
  dispatch  
}) => (
    <DatePicker      
      name={name}      
      label={label}
      value={value}
      helperText={error}
      minDate={minDate}
      maxDate={maxDate}
      error={Boolean(error)}
      onChange={onChange}     
      onError={(_, error) =>
        dispatch(formActions.stopSubmit(form, { [name]: error }))
      }
      disablePast      
      format={'dd.MM.yyyy'}
    />
  )
```

component.js =>> Redux-form component

```
import { DatePickerField } from 'utils/helper'

     <Field
        name={endDate}        
        component={DatePickerField}       
        onChange={value =>
          store.dispatch(maxDateChange(value))
        }       
      />
```

Expected Result : 
 =====================

```
action @@redux-form/CHANGE
meta: {…}, payload: Sat Jan 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)}

action     {type: "@@invoice/MAX_DATE_CHANGE", value: Sat Jan 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)}
```

Actual Result : 
 =======================

```
action @@invoice/MAX_DATE_CHANGE
value: {preventDefault: ƒ} <--value should be DatePicker current value.


action {type: "@@redux-form/CHANGE", meta: {…}, 
payload: Sat Jan 19 2019 15:49:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [look at the docs](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/field.md/#-code-onchange-event-newvalue-previousvalue-name-gt-void-code-optional-) for `Field` `onChange`, you'll see that the first parameter is the `event`, the second is the value. Also, that will be called before the `@@redux-form/CHANGE` event is dispatched, as it allows that event to be cancelled.

Comment: @erikras Thanks a ton for the solution mentioned below :                                       
Billing reducer could just listen for the @@redux-form/CHANGE action for that particular form and field. No need to dispatch both.

Comment: code below :                                                                 import { CHANGE } from 'redux-form'

if(action.type === CHANGE && action.meta.form === 'billingForm' && action.meta.field === 'billingDate') {
  return { ...state, billingDate: action.payload };
}

Comment: I was facing these issues while migrating from material-ui to material-ui@next, guys don't stop counting on Redux-form, its an awesome creation alongwith material-ui@next which 
now supports the Mobile responsiveness issues, only thing is sometimes one needs some documentation help to connect each other.